# I am a complete begginer in Python and i want to add an if statement inside a string

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I tried to do something like this:

```py
string='bla'+if string[len(string1)='x':
                       True:
                       deletter='blabla'
```

this is the code:

```py
tperfectcompus='am '+verb+if verb[len(verb)-2]='c':
                                True
                                theletter='esc'
```

Comment: `'bla' + ('something' if condition else 'something else')`

Comment: There is a way to do this in Python (the "ternary" statement as in @Barmar 's comment), but this is trying to be too clever by far.  Why not just use `string = 'blah';  if (whatever): string += 'blabla'`

Comment: How is concatenating a string with `True` supposed to work out?

Comment: Also you should be using `==` for comparison, not `=`

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm guessing this is some analogy to a C switch statement, rather than trying to append True.

Comment: A little more pythonic way of `verb[len(verb) - 2]` is by replacing it with `verb[-2]`